# Windows host file stopped working?

Tags: localhost, virtualhost, host

I have this lines in the hosts file

```
192.168.99.100  www.testlocal.com
```

and when i try to access them from the chrome it gives me this error

> This site can’t be reached
>
> testlocal.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

**Note**
This URL was working fine!
I have windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I think restoring the Host file to previous versions at the date it was working and that should do the trick

Regards,Pc Expert

Comment: It say there isn't any previous versions available.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, This URL is no longer working. it is giving me the error as well on my PC.

But if u are sure that this site is working so try following these steps :

1- Delete your Cache and Cookies.

2- Use Incognito Mode.

3- If this helps then temporarily disable your extensions to identify which one is causing the rendering problem. To do this go to chrome://extensions and uncheck Enabled for each extension one by one.

4- Reset Your Browser Settings.

5- Turn off hardware acceleration by going to Menu > Settings > Advanced Settings > Under 'System' uncheck Use hardware acceleration when available.

Let me know if this helps but in my opinion this URL is no longer available

```
                                             OR
```

If you are used to have virtual Wifi (Ad hoc) to access internet in your mobile. disable it and the problem will be gone, Also I found another way, Go to adapter setting and check if the IP address is set to automatic, manual IP often causes the same problem, Hope this will help.

Regards, PC Expert